# Equal column width using <col style> instead <col width>

Tags: css, html, html-table

When using the `width` attribute in a `<col>` tag, I can set to use equal or multiple widths for columns:

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed">
<colgroup>
  <col width="2*">
  <col width="1*">
  <col width="1*">
  <col width="1*">
</colgroup>
...
```

The `width` attribute has been deprecated, so I'd like to switch to `style="width..."`. Unfortunately the asterisk (*) notation for columns seems not to work there.

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed">
<colgroup>
  <col style="width: 2*">
  <col style="width: 1*">
  <col style="width: 1*">
  <col style="width: 1*">
</colgroup>
...
```

What is the correct was to specify equal or relative widths using CSS?

Comment: I suggest updating to scss and use mixins. Its much more cleaner and less redundant.

Comment: According to some references to Mixins (quick google search), only Chrome supports `@apply`. Unfortunately, I need a quite broad browser support for my web app.

Comment: You can built locally with scss and compile to css during production.

Comment: I very much hope that there will be an easier solution for (quite simple) relative widths. I'm working on a PHP web app and adding SCSS compilation in code that is created dynamically seems not to be a simple solution at first glance...

Comment: If its a large project with atleat 300+ loc of css, it is worth it. Yes, initial scss is a bit of handful, but once you get past that its a breeze